# Android Sprite Jump Physics and screen independence

Tags: android, screen, surfaceview, sprite, resolution-independence

I've been writing a 2D Surfaceview game for what seems an eternity now and I simply cannot get my head around screen independence for Android.

Basically, my sprite jumps like so:  Y value is decreased by an amount (I call it the 'step amount'), then the step amount is reduced by say, 1 and that goes on until the step amount is a negative number which then in effect gets added to the sprite's Y value and it 'falls' back down - works perfectly (This is the way I've always made sprites 'jump').

The problem comes when I run this on a different DPI screen - it still works, but the sprite jumps to a completely different height relative to the screen size.

I understand why this is happening, but I just can't work out a way to fix it!

How do I get it 'jumping' to the correct height on all screen res?  (I'm working mainly with 160 and 240 DPI at the moment)

Thanks, would really appreciate any comments.

Regards

Comment: Just make your initial step amount and decrement interval a function of your screen DPI instead of using fixed values for both?

Comment: Thanks Aroth, I'm creating my step amount by using 1 * (dpi/160) is this what you mean? On a 240 DPI screen I think it works out at 1.5 - I'm not sure how to work with 1/2 pixels in cases like this - any other help would be appreciated - thanks.